# Amazon DynamoDB Query for Items whose key contains a substring

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using an Amazon DynamoDB database, and I have a list of items with various strings as the key. I want to query for items whose key contains a substring. For example, if some of the keys are:

"abcd_aaa"

"abcd_bbb"

"abcd_ccc"

I want to query where a key contains "abcd" and these 3 items will be returned.  Is this possible?

Comment: I'm assuming by "query", you mean the actual DynamoDB [`Query`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) operation?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can only query the `hashKey` using the equality operator (`EQ`). That being said if those values ("abcd_aaa", "abcd_bbb", "abcd_ccc") belong to your `hashKey` then you have to provide them entirely. On the other hand, the `Query` operation does allow partial matching on the `rangeKey` with the option of a few additional comparison operators:

```
EQ | LE | LT | GE | GT | BEGINS_WITH | BETWEEN
```

See the `Query` [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) for more details.

One possibility would be to use a `hashKey and rangeKey` where the first part of your code would be the `hashKey` and the last the `rangeKey`, example:

```
hashKey : abcd
rangeKey : aaa
```

By doing this when you query by `hashKey` (abcd), you would receive all three records sorted by the `rangeKey`

Comment: Scan will work though it is not cost effective for this scenario.

Comment: The DynamoDB best practices goes to detail about how to construct sort keys out of hierarchical values, if you need to have more than two values as keys https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-sort-keys.html

Comment: @aumbadgah unfortunately that documentation doesn't provide an example of how to answer the question in the OP.

When you say "One possibility would be to use a hashKey and rangeKey where the first part of your code would be the hashKey and the last the rangeKey, example", what does that mean in terms of running a query? Do you set "rangeKey EQUALS aaa" and that acts as a contains? I dont see how your example returns "all three records sorted by the rangeKey"

Answer (score -5):

Scan will work

something like this

```
var params = {
      TableName: "TABLE",
      ScanFilter: {
           "id": {
                ComparisonOperator: "CONTAINS",
                AttributeValueList: ["abcd"]
           }
      }
 };

 var template = null;
 ddb.scan(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
           console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
      } else {
           //console.log("Query succeeded.");
           data.Items.forEach(function (item) {
                console.log(item);
           });
      }
 });
```

Comment: Scan might "work", but will consume capacity units for fetching the entire table contents and filter it afterwards. This is highly inefficient both in terms of performance and cost, which I think should be highlighted in the answer.